# Regular Expression word catching

Tags: regex, expression

So far I have put together this:

```
\b\S*[^\w\s^'^&]\S*\b
```

I am trying to catch whole words that are censored: I.E. `d*mn` or `d_mn` but don't want `&` or `'t` `'s` `'re` to match and also need to make it so that numbers like `1.23` are not matched.

My goal is to catch people trying to slip swear words in by using symbols in place of letters. So any word with a symbol should be caught except for things like apostrophes. The `&` symbol is a formatting thing and there can be one per letter max. So `'` and `&` are ok to be used. Numbers with decimals should work as they are not swear words. Things like `s**t` and `d_mn` or `d.mn` etc should be caught.

I need help with the number part.

I tried `^\d.\d` for `not digit dot digit` but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Your original RegEx seems to work (`\b\S*[^\w\s^'^&]\S*\b`)... Or do you mean it shouldn't match d*mn't?

Comment: Hi. It should match d*mn't but not 1.20 yet it does. Also it doesn't catch d_mn.

Comment: I added a revision to your question then. You didn't indicate that you want to match d_mn, and it was unclear (at least to me) that you *didn't* want to match 1.23.

Comment: You probably need to allow periods, outright - otherwise you'll catch periods at the ends of sentences and if not that, then when someone forgets to put a period at the end of a sentence.Like this.

Comment: I tried `.*?\b\S*[^\w\s^'&^(\d(?:\.\d{1,3})?]\S*\b.*?` and it seems to work for me.

Comment: On further testing its no catching words like d.mn or f_ck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using this one:

```
\b\p{L}*[\p{S}\p{P}]((\p{L}[\p{P}\p{S}])|([\p{P}\p{S}]\p{L})|(\p{L}))+\b
```

- `\p{L}` is any (unicode) letter
- `\p{S}` is any symbol
- `\p{P}` is any punctuation

The first part of the pattern (`\p{L}*[\p{S}\p{P}]`) ensures that the word must contain at least one symbol or punctuation. The rest of the pattern `((\p{L}[\p{P}\p{S}])|([\p{P}\p{S}]\p{L})|(\p{L}))+` specifies how things can repeat. Sequences of a letter followed by a punctuation/symbol, a punctuation/symbol followed by a letter, or a letter alone are acceptable.

To use this pattern in Java code make sure you first replace all backslash characters with double backslashes.

Comment: I copied this in to http://regexpal.com/ and tried a string like `This is a test of version 1.2.3 and h*pefully it works. if it doesn't that's not good! c**p ` and it did not catch anything.

Comment: @user2001545 Unfortunately it seems that JavaScript does not support `\p` symbols. Since you are using Java as your language please test against a Java regex tester such as: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: I tried `.*?\b\S*[^\w\s^'&^(\d(?:\.\d{1,3})?]\S*\b.*?` and it seems to work for me. Except for words like f.ck. SO that's not so great.

Comment: Hey Sina yours works well. Thanks for the link too. Lemme test in Eclipse... Nope sorry it catches apostrophes that are normal in text.

Comment: How do I change the `\p{S}` to add in `'` and `&` symbol negation?

Comment: Modified by other person on here named MikeM: `\b(?!.*[&'])\p{L}*[\p{S}\p{P}]((\p{L}[\p{P}\p{S}])|([\p{P}\p{S}]\p{L})|(\p{L}))+\b` seems to work. Thanks

Comment: @user2001545 You can instead enumerate all possible punctuations and symbols which are allowed (all except `'` and `&`), and replace with all occurances of `[\p{P}\p{S}]`. E.g., replace `[\p{P}\p{S}]` with `[*_\.!@#$~^<>]`. It would be much faster than the negative lookahead of the other pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my tentative answer:

`\b[a-zA-Z]*(?:[^\w\s^'&]|_)+[a-zA-Z]+\b`

Using `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\S` no longer includes numbers.

**EDIT**: It now requires that the word end in a letter. I also made it so it will match repeated special characters, like in `a$$hole`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it didn't catch anything. The one I had didn't have issues with periods or question marks at the end of sentences.

Comment: What language is this in? JavaScript? ...and you're right, it doesn't catch the period at the end of a sentence because it would be a word boundary. My bad. It would catch it in the middle though.

Comment: Would it even be possible to distinguish between the end of a sentence and a word with a full stop at the end?

Comment: Huh. I'm testing this with Java. Well, a Regex parser that lets me specify the parsing language as Java. You're certain it didn't match anything?

Comment: Which parser are you using, maybe that is my issue.

Comment: Yeh I just put in in Eclipse and ran in java and it didn't catch anything.  Thanks for the help I think It will just have to do the way it is.

Comment: I changed some things and used a different way to do it and yours works almost. Its catching words that end in punctuation, but catching all the required words. How can it be changed to allow punctuation at the end?

Comment: @user2001545: Which one - the first one, or the big one using the `|` separator?

Comment: @user2001545: Try my updated answer. It requires the match to end in a letter (but can contain punctuation anywhere within - including the first character.)